# How to resize Prestigio PAP4044Duo's partitions?

Tags: insufficient-memory, partitions

I have a Prestigio PAP4044Duo with 4.1.1 Android on it. It has a Internal Memory of 786MB + Internal Memory Card of 1.77 GB. Since all the applications are stored in the Internal Memory I'm running fast out of space on it. I have read through forums and most topics are referring to SD cards, and all the applications I've found to moving Apps from the Internal Memory are also referring to SD cards.

So, is it possible to repartition the size of the internal memory and the internal memory card to get the following size:

- Internal Memory - 1.7GB
- Internal Memory Card - 700MB

If it is possible, where should I start, and are there any step by step tutorials that someone with not much experience could follow?

Answer (score 3):

### Is it possible to resize partitions?

Yes, it is theoretically possible, **but** it may not work on your device. If you're ready to take a risk with your device (if something goes wrong, it may be bricked until you find what's wrong with it), go ahead. Also, this modification isn't recommended for beginners. Also notice that by this you will factory reset your device (all app data will be gone). You'll need:

- A rooted device with custom recovery
- Basic knowledge of how ADB works
- Basic knowledge of how partitions and partiton tables work
- Patience and time since this could (and will) probably have some obstacles since you're a beginner and these tutorials aren't made for your specific device.

I successfully resized my partition using [this tutorial on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2712253), however, I skipped some steps in the way, since they were directed at different devices (Xperia phones), therefore, not all steps are compatible.

***This tutorial may not support your device, so proceed with caution***

I will try to briefly summarize what is going on that tutorial.
*What will we do:*

1. We will back up all the files present on the internal SD card (this is optional)
2. We will delete `/sdcard`partition (that's internal, emulated "SD card"), and we will delete `/data`partition (that's where your phone data, including apps, is stored)
3. We will then create new `/sdcard` and `/data`partitions, but this time, they will be resized so that you'd have more space for apps.
4. If we backed up SD card earlier, we will now restore the original content of the internal SD

**I assume you have worked with ADB and that you have a custom recovery present on your device (if you don't fulfil these requirements, get familiar with those before proceeding)**

Okay, before we start, you'll need to download fs-utils.zip from [this XDA page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2712253). These are file system utilities which we'll use later. Unzip this file and place it a folder, somewhere on the external SD card (e.g. /sdcard/fs-utils)
Also, enable "USB debugging" on your phone, located in "Developer Options" on more recent devices, or "Applications" on older devices.

### Backing up files from Internal SD card (optional)

Okay, this one's pretty simple, you copy the files from internal memory to anywhere you want (i.e. PC, external SD card).

### Editing the partition table

This is where it becomes tricky, so be sure that everything is working before starting this, and make sure that your phone has enough battery (just in case).

- Enter the recovery on your phone.
- Connect to ADB
- Execute following commands

  ```
  umount /storage
  parted /dev/block/mmcblk0
  print
  ```

  This should print out the partition table, like:

  `Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
  1      131kB   2228kB  2097kB               TA
  2      2228kB  3801kB  1573kB               Boot
  3      3801kB  5374kB  1573kB               Boot2
  4      6291kB  27.3MB  21.0MB               Kernel
  5      27.3MB  28.3MB  1049kB               TZ
  6      29.4MB  32.5MB  3146kB               modemst1
  7      33.6MB  36.7MB  3146kB               modemst2
  8      37.7MB  40.9MB  3146kB               fsg
  9      40.9MB  46.1MB  5243kB               ramdump
  10      46.1MB  54.5MB  8389kB  ext4         apps_log
  11      54.5MB  71.3MB  16.8MB               FOTAKernel
  12      71.3MB  2120MB  2049MB  ext4         System
  13      2120MB  2620MB  500MB   ext4         Cache
  14      2620MB  5692MB  3072MB  ext4         Userdata
  15      5692MB  15.6GB  9942MB  ext4         SDCard`

In this example, `Userdata` partition is on the 14th place, and `SDCard` is in the 15th. Notice how the `Userdata` starts at 2620MB, and ends at 5692MB, and `SDCard` begins where `Userdata` ends, and finishes at 15.6GB. Mark these numbers, as we'll use them when we create the new partitions.

Following this example, we will remove these partitions:

```
rm 14
rm 15
```

Now, we calculate new sizes of the new partitions. **Notice:** You need to have emulated SD Card on your system, don't completely remove it, it is hardcoded into the system, and removing could break the functionality of the device.

For example, if we want to increase the size of the `Userdata` to 6000MB, we simply add 6000MB to 2620MB (where the partition starts), to get the position where the partition ends. In that case, it would end at 8620MB. `SDCard` follows after the `Userdata`, so it begins at 8620MB and ends at 15.6GB.

So, after calculating the sizes, we enter:

```
mkpartfs logical ext2 2620 8620 (change the numbers for your device)
name 14 Userdata
mkpartfs logical ext2 8620 15.6GB (again, change the numbers)
name 15 SDCard
quit
```

Now, the space is allocated for these new partitions, but they aren't correctly formatted yet. So, in your recovery, format your internal SD card (sdcard0 or whatever it's called).

Now, in ADB, navigate to the folder on the external SD card, where the fs-utils are located:

```
cd /sdcard/fs-utils (change as appropriate)
```

After that, enter these commands, one by one:

```
tune2fs -j /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
e2fsck -fpDC0 /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
```

Now, the partitions are formatted.

You can reboot the phone now.

Try to write something to the SDCard, just to check do you have write permissions on it, and if you don't, enter (via ADB):

```
su
chown -R 2800:2800 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0
```

That should fix the problem.

After this, you can restore the backed up files to your SDCard.

*Since this is my first community post, I encourage users to edit and expand this post as needed.*