# The SamsungGalaxyAce doesn't let me download apps!Even with a huge SD Card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, internal-sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and a 4GB SD card, I only have one app that is whatsapp, and When I try to download another app That is 40MG(a lot less than 4GB), it says insufficient Space, but I go to settings and it says that I have 3.69GB of space on SD card, and on the phone's space that comes with it says 20 MG available, so I have 3.69GB,and 20MG, and it doesn't let me download apps!What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the device info is correct [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_ace_s5830-3724.php) then your device's internal memory is 158MB (quite low IMO) in total out of which you can use [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)(see **Userdata** in it) and [Diskusage](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111060/96277) (both <1MB individually)to see how much space is used and is available. You can then uninstall any app that you may have installed at some time but don't remember.

However, I don't see much scope here since the issue would arise again sooner or later considering the (very low) storage set by OEM.

Note that the storage used by apps is `/data` which is different from the external SD card that you've of any size. Some apps until Android 4.2+ can transfer data files (`.obb`) into external SD card rather easily but it is a painful job in above versions now.

Answer (score 0):

Apps do not download directly to the SD card, even as far back as Gingerbread. You must have adequate built-in storage to do this. Once installed you can move some bits of some apps to the SD card, but internal storage will still be required for some things. Kitkat and Lollipop make this even worse by effectively making the SD card read-only.

I suggest bringing up WhatsApp's app info and seeing how much cache space it's taking up. Clearing cache on apps -- even built-in ones -- can help significantly.