# Samsung Galaxy J5 J500F Bricked - How to unbrick?

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy J500F. Trying to get more storage, I moved all of the system files to the sd card and now the phone won't turn on. The PC will not recognize the phone (no ding, no device manager detect).

Not able to get into recovery mode. Im not able to charge the battery either.

How to recover a phone in this condition? I used two JIG's (one I bought and one I made) it didn't work.

I have downloaded the firmware but I can't flash the phone (or can I?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you moved the `/system` file elsewhere, then your device is *bricked* (moving `/system` files to create space [doesn't help](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110929/131553) as that space is not available to user for data)

Having done this without realising the implications, it is unlikely you would be able to flash stock ROM on your own. It's best you take it to service centre where it may be resurrected using ODIN /JTAG tool

Comment: Could a sd card flash work?

Comment: No, it won't. You have removed the complete system, it is not possible. No offence meant but you did this without realising the fall out (like I did recently on my new phone and bricked it)- it's best to have capable hands that have the right tools to do it. You could buy a JTAG and experiment but it may not be worth the cost or time

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will contact a repair shop that has JTAG and see if this fixes the problem. Great help by the way. :)

Comment: You are welcome. All the best

Comment: JTAG is the last resort, it may be possible to recover otherwise too by ODIN - let them decide

Comment: @beeshyams `/system` is just a partition. One cannot do critical damage by altering it.

Comment: @Nikolette What do you see by booting the phone while holding the `Volume Down` and `Home` buttons?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman;  I ignored that option as battery is not charging and for a first timer getting into ODIN and pit files would be too daunting. Also note that recovery option isn't working, so felt download mode also wouldn't

Comment: @beeshyams This is what I was tempted to think as well, but I feel that we cannot give a precise answer unless OP elaborates on `[…] moved all the system files […]`, because they could've moved far more than just the `/system` partition's contents.

Answer (score 1):

You would still be able to boot it into download (ODIN) mode,
Just press and hold <kbd>Vol</kbd> +  <kbd>Power key</kbd> buttons until you see the download mode.
After that connect it to your PC and run Odin and flash your stock-rom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you can't repair your Device. The Folder "/system" gives the ability for your Smartphone. Without it, you can't use it. Just like the System32 on Windows, removing it causes BSOD (Blue screen of Death).

I recommend you to take into a really smart repair shop and the motherboard needs to be probably replaced. If you don't want that, then try to flash the stock rom (yes, it deletes Root too but try SP Flash Tool and ODIN).